# ASP.NET Core Web API: JWT token does not set "HttpContext User"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, google-signin, httpcontext

I have a JWT token implementation in my app and I implemented Google login. But now, `HttpContext.User` claims are not set.

Here is my `startup.cs`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = CLIENT_ID
            options.ClientSecret = SECRET
            options.SaveTokens = true;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
          {
              options.SaveToken = true;
              options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
              options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
              {
                  ValidateIssuer = true,
                  ValidateAudience = true,
                  ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                  ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                  IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
              };

              options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
              {
                  OnMessageReceived = context =>
                  {
                      context.Token = context.Request.Cookies[CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme];
                      context.HttpContext.User = context.Principal;
                      return Task.CompletedTask;
                  },
              };
          }).AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

And I log in like this:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Email, Password, false, true);
```

This is how I create the JWT token:

```
var authClaims = new List<Claim>
                     {
                         new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.UserName),
                         new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                         new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.FirstName)
                     };

var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(["JWT:Secret"]));

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                            issuer: ["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                            audience: ["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                            expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                            claims: authClaims,
                            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                            );
```

Normally, it sets `HttpContext.User` and claims and I can check

```
var userEmail = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value
```

but now, this returns null.

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: did you add the middleware to the request pipeline?

Comment: Your default authentication scheme is `"cookies"` instead of `"bearer"`. Can you show the controller with the action?

Comment: Either add `[Authorize(AuthenticationScheme=JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` to your controller method, or set the `options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme=JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`

Comment: If you want to enable both cookie+bearer auth, you need to create 2 seperate controllers each time, so that's why you need to move logic to a service and inject it in your controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution. I just add   `await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false,"JwtBearer");` and resolved. Thanks!