Identity framework JWT Token Not Validating in Middleware: HttpContext.User is Empty and IsAuthenticated is False
I am implementing JWT authentication in my ASP.NET Core application. The token is successfully generated, and I can see it in the authorization header of requests. However, when I try to access HttpContext.User in a custom middleware, the user has no claims, and IsAuthenticated is always false.
Here is my setup - JWT token generation:
public async Task<string> GenerateJWTTokenAsync(AppUser user)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName.ToString())
    };

    if (user.IsSuperAdmin)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim("isSuperAdmin", "true"));
    }

    var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Jwt:SecretKey"]));
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        audience: configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        claims: claims,
        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15),
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
    );

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}

JWT configuration in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:SecretKey"])),
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});

Custom middleware:
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var token))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Token: {token}");
    }

    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"User Authenticated: {context.User.Identity.Name}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User is not authenticated");
    }

    await _next(context);
}

Issue

I receive the token in the Authorization header
Despite this, HttpContext.User is empty, and IsAuthenticated is always false.

What I tried

Verified the middleware order (UseAuthentication and UseAuthorization come before my custom middleware)
Checked the authorization header format (Bearer <token>)
Enabled verbose logging for JwtBearerMiddleware, but no errors are logged
Manually inspected the token using JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ReadJwtToken() in the middleware, and it seems valid
Ensured TokenValidationParameters match the token properties (Issuer, Audience, SecretKey, etc.)


I see that post in StackOverflow, maybe it will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75299563/asp-net-core-web-api-jwt-token-does-not-set-httpcontext-user
